# How can I show that my aws ec2 instances, and/or s3 data are in a particular region?

Tags: amazon-web-services

For government compliance, I need to be show that the data i am storing, and where the data is being computed, is in a particular region.

Is there a standard method that AWS provide, or a standard way to show this?

The only ways I have thought of are by taking a screenshot of the regions the aws instances are are running in, or by showing that the ip addresses of the ec2 instances are in the region claimed.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html), services/domain property.

Answer (score 1):

[AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/) may be the correct service for you. Here's the AWS blurb

> AWS Config is a service that enables you to assess, audit, and
>   evaluate the configurations of your AWS resources. Config continuously
>   monitors and records your AWS resource configurations and allows you
>   to automate the evaluation of recorded configurations against desired
>   configurations. With Config, you can review changes in configurations
>   and relationships between AWS resources, dive into detailed resource
>   configuration histories, and determine your overall compliance against
>   the configurations specified in your internal guidelines. This enables
>   you to simplify compliance auditing, security analysis, change
>   management, and operational troubleshooting.

You can also use [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html). It returns a variety of data, but the key one you want is "region".

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document

{
  "region" : "us-west-2"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'll have a look at AWS Config, and hopefully mark you as the accepted answer.